# No controls visible on S3

Tags: android, image, amazon-s3, radio-button, visibility

I face the following issue - come of the people that downloaded my new space simulation game (but not all) are complaining, that they do not see any controls on their devices. The problem seems to be present on S3 devices only. I am with S3 myself, and everything is appearing as designed.

The controls are implemented as custom radio buttons, I will post the code below, however my question is:
What could cause such different behavior?

```
public class CenteredRadioButton extends RadioButton {

private Drawable buttonDrawable;

public CenteredRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CompoundButton, 0, 0);
    buttonDrawable = a.getDrawable(1);
    setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radio_empty);
}

public void setCustomDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    buttonDrawable = drawable;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (buttonDrawable != null) {
        buttonDrawable.setState(getDrawableState());
        final int verticalGravity = getGravity() & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
        final int height = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        int y = 0;

        switch (verticalGravity) {
            case (Gravity.BOTTOM) : {
                y = getHeight() - height;
                break;
            } case (Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL) : {
                y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
                break;
            }
        }

        int buttonWidth = buttonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int buttonLeft = (getWidth() - buttonWidth) / 2;
        buttonDrawable.setBounds(buttonLeft, y, buttonLeft + buttonWidth, y + height);
        buttonDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the logcat the users sent you through Android Developer Console

Comment: There is error, he just 1-starred the application, saying that on S3 there are no controls. This is the second time someone reports the same issue...

Comment: maybe because they are using custom roms 1!! custom roms causes aloot of troubles to the developers as some applications wont work on custom roms. if you using stock rom . i recommend you to flash custom rom and test it on it. just to clear things up. and by custom roms i'm referring to CM.

Comment: Thanks, I also think this could be the issue, however even if I test it on my device and if I reproduce it, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Today I got another feedback from an S3 user - he claims to be with the latest original firmware and is still unable to see the controls. Any other ideas why images could bot be loaded in an app? We are talking here about statically loaded images, bundled in the app - R.drawable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that GIF image format is not entirely supported in some Android versions, for more information you could take a look at the thread below and a big THANK YOU to Rich for solving the issue!

[Images not loading on Galaxy S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146250/images-not-loading-on-galaxy-s3)